# Swith to hand tool when opening pdf in an html page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have pdf's that will be viewed with a touch screen and no mouse. I would like to switch to the hand tool, for scrolling, when they are loaded in the web page and not have the user select it from the menu. I see other options out there but none use the plugin native hand tool, which is what I would like to do.

Comment: If you're using the native PDF viewer you don't really have any kind of control over that. It's completely handed off to the browser.

Comment: Yes, it's the acrobat plugin. If that's what you mean by native.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. Sorry, you're out of luck. I've been working with embedded PDFs a lot lately and came to the same conclusion.